# Fixed point of multiplicative order of $2 \bmod 2n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the sequence ([OEIS 2326](https://oeis.org/A002326)) $a_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$) such that $a_n>0$ is the least positive integer such that $$2^{a_n}\equiv 1[2n+1]$$

This is easy to prove that $$1+\log_2(n+1)\le a_n\le 2n+1$$

But what is the set $F=\left\{n\mid a_n=n\right\}$ ? Is $F$ infinite ?

Comment: You have a lower bound for $a_n$ in terms of a strictly increasing function in $n$...

Comment: @Tomas I'm not sure what you want to explain.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the notation. Now, it does become an interesting question! (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't too hard to see that if we want $a_n=n$, then $2n+1$ must be a prime $2n+1=p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$.

Indeed, observe that since $n$ is the order of $2 \pmod{2n+1}$, we necessarily have $n \mid \phi(2n+1)$ and also $n\mid \lambda(2n+1)$, where $\lambda(m)$ is the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Note that $0<\phi(2n+1) \leq 2n$ so $\phi(2n+1)=n, 2n$. In any case, we have $(\phi(2n+1), 2n+1)=1$, so $2n+1$ must be squarefree.

If $pq \mid 2n+1$ for distinct primes $pq$, then $\phi(2n+1)<2n$, so $0<\lambda(2n+1) \leq \frac{\phi(2n+1)}{2}<\frac{2n}{2}=n$, a contradiction.

Therefore $2n+1$ is prime. Write $2n+1=p$. Note that $2$ must be a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, since $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Therefore $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$.

---

However now we need to characterise all primes $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$ such that $2$ can be written as $g^2 \pmod{p}$, where $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p}$ (so order of $2$ will be $\frac{p-1}{2}=n$).

This doesn't seem too easy; consider the related problem of whether there are infinitely many primes such that $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p}$, which to my knowledge remains unsolved despite significant progress (See [Artin's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain a little bit more 1/ Why $x$ must be square free if $\gcd(\phi(x),x)=1$ ? 2/ Why $\lambda(2n+1)\le\frac{\phi(2n+1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Xoff 1) Write $$x=\prod_{i=1}^{m}{p_i^{a_i}}$$ then $$\phi(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{m}{p_i^{a_i-1}(p_i-1)}$$ If $a_i \geq 2$, we have $p_i \mid x$ and $p_i \mid \phi(x)$. Thus if $\gcd(\phi(x), x)=1$, each $a_i \leq 1$ so $x$ is squarefree.


2) $$\lambda(\prod_{i=1}^{m}{p_i^{a_i}})=lcm(p_1^{a_1-1}(p_1-1), p_2^{a_2-1}(p_2-1), \ldots p_m^{a_m-1}(p_m-1))$$ Compare this to $\phi$ which gives the product of the terms. If we have at least two odd $p_i$, we would have at least $2$ even terms, so taking $lcm$ of the terms would give at most half the result from taking the product of the terms.

Comment: Thank you, this is very well explained.